# Error 503 Service unavailable

Tags: symfony

just started with Symfony2 and already have a problem that i can not solve.
Installed the Symfony2 demo app on a VPS with debian. but trying to open it give me a "503 Service unavailable".

I used 'symfony demo' to install to /var/www/symfony_demo/
then added a symdemo.conf file to /etc/apache2/sites-available that look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost XX.XXX.XX.XXX

<VirtualHost XX.XXX.XX.XXX>
ServerName symblog.dev
DocumentRoot "/var/www/symfony_demo/web"
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory "/var/www/symfony_demo/web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

XX.XXX.XX.XXX = public server IP

and activated it with `a2ensite symdemo.conf`

I thought that would work, but opening the IP give me the error message.
and trying to open app_dev.php give me `not allowed to access this file`

Could someone please give me a tip?

Comment: Check your log files in app/logs/prod...

Comment: have you created/setup your database correctly?

Comment: app/logs is empty. no file, no directory.
database? no. did not know i need one for the demo.
edit: looks like it's using sqlite pointing to ''sqlite:///%kernel.root_dir%/data/blog.sqlite'. guess that should work, no?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Looks like i fixed it. Following this tutorial: http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/07/symfony2-jobeet-day-1-starting-up-the-project/

just activate mod_rewrite with `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache. that's it.